# I need Sql help in a query

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

what query would I use to do the following

> Name1 Version1 xAmount
>
> Name1 Version2 xAmount
>
> Name2 Version1 xAmount
>
> Name2 Version2 xAmount
>
> Name2 Version3 xAmount
>
> Name3 Version1 xAmount

according to this The latest version for Name1 is Version2, and the latest version for Name2 is Version3, and Name3 is Version1.

How would i create a query to grab each name with the latest version, assuming the latest version is an integer or something like 1.2a and 1.2b

Answer (score 0):

use the following

```
select Name,Version, Amount
From T1,(select Name,max(Version) as Version From T1 Group By Name) as T2
Where T1.Name=T2.Name and T1.Version=T2.Version
```

and if you have an ID for the table

```
select Name,Version, Amount
From T1,(select max(ID) as ID From T1 Group By Name) as T2
Where T1.ID=T2.ID
```

Or

```
select Name,Version, Amount
From T1
Where T1.ID IN (select max(ID) as ID From T1 Group By Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I strongly recommend you to keep a numeric column indicating wich iteration of the version it is, even if you have a column with the name. So, assuming you do that, then the solution for what you want its very simple:

```
SELECT Name, MAX(version) as MaxVersion
FROM Table
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: Where is the corresponding xAmount ?

Comment: Actually, to get the xAmount value, you need to use the first soultion given by @Waleed A.K., I neglected to see his answer.